# Ipyparallel and numba (jit)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jit, numba

I've been trying to run a code using ipyparallel. However, since some of my functions pass through jit. This ends up in the ipython console not doing anything and freezing. Here is an example:

```
import time
import numpy
from numba import jit

from ipyparallel import Client
client = Client()  # create client and direct view to all engines available
dview = client[:]
dview.block = True


with dview.sync_imports():
    import numpy

@jit
def TestingFnc(x):
    a=x[0]
    b=x[1]
    c=x[2]
    Result=0
    for i in range(100000):
        Result = Result + ((a+i)**2 + (b-i)**3) /(c+i)**3
    return numpy.array([Result,1])

d=numpy.array([[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,1.],[0.,0.,2]])
Results = dview.map(TestingFnc, d)
```

Without the @jit, the code runs in parallel.